# Find area using double integral and polar coordinates

Tags: integration, area

Find the area enclosed by $ρ=1+cos(\theta)$. I can not find the angle of the function to define the limits of the integrals.

This would be the graph of the function:

[image: Graph of ρ=1+cos(\theta)]

What I was trying to do, because of the symmetry of the function, was:
$$2\int _0^α\int _0^{1+cos\left(\theta \right)}\:ρ\:dρd\theta$$

However, I can't correctly find the angle $α$. I would highly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\alpha$ is the angle at which $r=1+\cos(\theta) =0$,  therefore  $$ A= 2\int _0^\pi \int _0^{1+\cos\left(\theta \right)}\:r\:\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: You are correct! Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for your attention.